# T-SQL Select data from multiple days between certain times

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, datetime

In my table I have minute data about daily temperature measurements. The table looks like:

```
DateTime timestamp, Float temperature
```

I would like to have the temperatures on different dates between a certain interval and then only show the temperature between 7am and 8pm.

I know how to get the data between dates:

```
SELECT [timestamp],[temperature]
  FROM [meteo_data]
  WHERE [timestamp] BETWEEN '2012-11-10' and '2012-11-17'
```

How to I implement the time restriction (7am - 8pm) as well?

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are on `SQL Server 2008 or above`, you can use `TIME datatype`

```
SELECT [timestamp],[temperature]
FROM [meteo_data]  
WHERE [timestamp] BETWEEN '2012-11-10' and '2012-11-17'
AND CONVERT(TIME,[timestamp]) BETWEEN '19:00:00' AND '20:00:00'
```

**EDIT:** Also it is recommended to use `ISO (yyyymmdd)` date format when using date as a string. i.e.

```
BETWEEN '20121110' and '20121117'
```

Answer (score 1):

The DateTime and TimeStamp values should contain precision you need, so

```
SELECT [timestamp],[temperature]
FROM [meteo_data]  
WHERE [timestamp] BETWEEN '2012-11-10' and '2012-11-17'
AND RIGHT([timestamp], 12) BETWEEN '19:00:00.000' AND '20:00.00.000'
```

You may need to adjust how many characters you are evaluating in the RIGHT predicate depending on the precision in your database. But the idea is to take all the parts that constitute the hours, minutes, seconds and miliseconds and restrict that to just those between the hours you require.

Comment: Hi Simon, thanks. I get the idea however it does not seem to work. I just get nothing back if I include the last line...

Comment: Ok I get it, the right return the folloiwng: [2012  6:26PM    ], I think I can solve it now.

Comment: Great, sounds like it's almost there then. It looks like there are 11 characters, not the 12 I assumed with my answer. If you change the last clause to 11 does it return the correct data?